# Adding Ubuntu 12.10 windows management feature to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, updates

I tried 12.10 and I decided to stay to with 12.04. The only thing I liked on 12.10 was when all the windows you have open, you could spread all out and close the windows you didn't want to keep. You use the windows key with w to do this I think. Is there a way to add this feature to 12.04 without upgrading to 12.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to upgrade Unity and Compiz to the Quantal versions —which are very different internally from Precise versions—, but it’s a risky process and I don’t think it’s worth the hassle TBH.